# PictureBox won't appear C#

Tags: c#, forms, picturebox

I am trying to do a logical gates program. I'm trying to create a `PictureBox` with the class NOT, the problem is that it doesn't appear when I call the create method inside form1 and the `PictureBox`won't appear when I click the list item. The problem is (I think) that it doesn't know that it is in form1 even though I use the `FindForm()` method.
And call it from forms

```
---Source Code for NoT class---

class NOT: Shape
{
    PictureBox px = new PictureBox();    
    Image img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\NOT.png");
    public NOT(int x, int y) : base(x,y)
    {
        px.FindForm();
        px.Visible = true;
        px.Enabled = true;

    }

    public override void CreatePicture()
    {
        Point p1 = new Point(xx, yy);
        px.Image = img;
        px.Location = p1;

        px.Show();      
    }
}


---Source code for the SHape Class---
abstract class Shape
{
    protected int xx, yy;    //private Point location;

    public Shape(int X, int Y)
    {
        xx = X;
        yy = Y;
    }

    public abstract void CreatePicture();
}
private void nOTToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nt.CreatePicture();


    }
NOT nt = new NOT(12,23);
```

---

Comment: but you are never telling the picture box that it should live inside the form! so it lies in the space (or in the memory of the program, but nobody draws it)..

Answer (score 2):

You need to associate the picture box with a form by adding it to the forms Controls collection.  Calling `FindForm()` only returns the currently assigned form; in your case it will be returning `null`.

```
public override void CreatePicture(Form form)
{
    Point p1 = new Point(xx, yy);
    px.Image = img;
    px.Location = p1;

    form.Controls.Add(px);

    px.Show();      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add the pictureBox. For example, if the PictureBox is in a panel:

```
panel.Controls.Add();
```

if it is in the form you just put `Controls.Add();`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must place PictureBox to the form for draw it:

```
PictureBox px = new PictureBox();
....
px.Parent = YouFormForExample;//Component who is draw this picture box
```